# Pulling a deep property from a json without using lodash get

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So we've got a sample json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Sample description",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "some git url"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node"
  ],
  "author": "Anonymous",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and here is our node.js script

```
var obj = require('./package.json');
console.log(obj[process.argv[2]]);
```

When I execute `node getval.js version`, it works. However, when I execute `node getval.js repository.url`, I get undefined.

When I change the code to the one below, it works. However, I don't want to hardcode the key values

```
console.log(obj['repository']['url']);
```

Comment: `process.argv[2].split('.')`, then use `for` loop, `reduce`, or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an object `obj` and a `"repository.url"` `key`, you can get the deep value with

```
var val = key.split(".").reduce((o,k)=>o[k],obj);
```

Demonstration:

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Sample description",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "some git url"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node"
  ],
  "author": "Anonymous",
  "license": "ISC"
};

var key = "repository.url";

var val = key.split(".").reduce((o,k)=>o[k],obj);

document.write("result: \"" + val + "\"");
```

Now, imagine you want something which doesn't throw an exception when some properties are missing, for example `"repository.language.version"`, then you could do

```
var val = key.split(".").reduce((o={},k)=>o[k],obj);
```

Comment: I'm going to test it now.

Comment: Any js book that you can recommend to me reading Denys Séguret? Thanks!

Comment: @devwannabe I'm not sure, but I've heard good things about "Eloquent JavaScript" and you should make sure you don't miss ES6 (either read an up to date book or read a dedicated one)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the key on the `.` before accessing them on the object

```
var keys = argv[2].split('.');
var result = obj;
keys.forEach(function(key){
    result = result[key]
});
return result;
```