# Issues using eval() to parse JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, eval, kde-plasma

For a widget that gets prices from exchange APIs using exchange api urls and json keys:

```
var Url = 'https://insert.api.url/';
var Key = 'insert.json.key';

request(Url, function(req) {
    var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    var rate = eval("data." + Key); 
    callback(rate);
    });
    return true;
}

function request(Url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = (function(xhr) {
        return function() {
            callback(xhr);
        }
    })(xhr);
    xhr.open('GET', Url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

This works as it should on some API's e.g when:

```
var Url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD';
var Key = 'result.XXBTZUSD.c[0]';
```

but it does not work in some cases e.g when:

```
var Url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/';
var Key = '0[price_usd]';
```

I get an eval() error with "expected token".

how can i solve this?

Comment: you're trying to eval some invalid JavaScript: `data.0[price_usd]`

Comment: Use `var rate = eval("data" + Key); ` and `.result.XXBTZUSD.c[0]`, `[0][price_usd]`. Note, `.` is part of the key, not rate eval expression.

Comment: Don't use eval but a deep property access like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192518/pulling-a-deep-property-from-a-json-without-using-lodash-get

Comment: @dfsq thanks!! this was the solution. it should have been data[0].price_usd.

Comment: @DenysSéguret  Thanks i'll look into it.